# Arduino Mega to Raspberry pi 3 Uart communication stops after a short while

Tags: arduino, usb, uart

I have been trying to setup a data stream from Arduino to rpi using an USB to Uart converter. I am using 4 startbytes and then reading all 36 bytes of data at once. Baudrate, parity and stopbits are set correctly. Python code for data collection in rpi is bellow:

```
self.__input_serial = serial.Serial(input_port, baudrate=250000, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, timeout=0.01)

def readVESC(self, buffer, new_vesc):
    num_of_bytes = 36
    start_bytes = []
    while True:  
        current_byte = self.__input_serial.read(1)
        if current_byte != b'\xff':
            start_bytes = []
            continue
        start_bytes.append(current_byte)
        if start_bytes == [b'\xff', b'\xff', b'\xff', b'\xff']:
            temp = self.__input_serial.read(num_of_bytes)
            print(temp)
```

The problem is, that after a while (max 30 secs), raspberry stops reading data completely and the code hangs at the `self.__input_serial.read()` section. After restarting the script, data starts to flow correctly and the process repeats.
Using timeout and re-opening the serial didnt seem to work at all. When I played with the Baudrate, it just changed the average time it took the serial to crash. Using some kinds of delays, just seemed to delay the incoming crash. It seems to happen pretty much at random, not after any given number of bytes or time. Any recommendations on possible causes/solutions?

EDIT-my solution: Turned out, the serial input buffer overflew, because arduino was sending data way faster than rpi processed it. I implemented a simple handshake, as shown in these codes. This seems to get rid of the issue completely. Ardu9ino:

```
#ifdef OUTPUT_BINARY
  if(Serial.available()){
     int handshake = 0;
     handshake = Serial.read();           //send data after request comes from raspberry
     if(handshake == 1){
        sendDataBinary();
     }
  }
```

And rpi:

```
    def __readVESC(self, buffer, new_vesc):
    num_of_bytes = 36
    buffer1 = []

    while True:
        #time.sleep(1)
        self.__input_serial.write(struct.pack('>B', 1)) # data request to arduino
        for i in range(num_of_bytes):
            buffer1.append(self.__input_serial.read(1))
```

Comment: As a test, Can you use the RPI's UART from the IO header? This might isolate USB driver issues. Also, Are you sure your baud rate is correct? Does the Arduino has the same rate?

Comment: I am sure about the baudrate. Sadly I cannot use the the Rpi GPIO pins, since I am using a Navio2 shield. However, I have been using the same USB port and uart converter to send data from Rpi to Jetson nano, with great success, so I would not think the USB port to be at fault here.

Comment: You have **highly unusual** serial settings there which are an immediate suspect, where did you get the idea that those would be appropriate?.  Of course you *know* the required baud rate - **it is in your own Arduino code** which you have failed to include in the question.

Comment: Additionally your timeout is unreasonably short; there's a fairly good chance it gets hit during your attempted 36 byte read resulting in less data actually being received.  If you are going to use a short timeout you are basically treating the interface as a quasi non-blocking one and need to handle incomplete reads yourself.

Comment: Sorry about not posting the .ino code, I am using simple Serial.write() function , that is why I reassured about the baudrate in the question :). About the timeout, I have tried higher or none at all, but the crash seems to be happening at random moments. Sometimes in the 36 byte read, sometimes when waiting for start bytes.. The serial settings is the same as in the rest of my project, but i played with those as well and they seem to have no effect at all, regarding this problem. I was trying to think of a best way to restart the serial port, if an incomplete message occurs?

Comment: Your 250 baud is a bit too high, and easy to get out of sync, and hangs the system.  To troubleshoot, I suggest to start with 9,600 8N1.

Comment: Sadly lowering the baudrate and using basic serial settings did not seem to have solved the crashing issue. it just prolonged the time before it crashed. So I was thinking, if there could be some sort of hidden serial buffer I do not know about that overflows, but I am just guessing at this point.